# Searching in open questions only?

Tags: discussion, search

Is there a way to search against ONLY questions (e.g. no matches from answers)?

Is there a way to filter out results from closed questions (only get matches from open ones)?

Answer (score 5):

[`is:question`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is:question) will search for questions only.
[`closed:no`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed:no) will search for open questions only.

[`hi is:question closed:no`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hi%20is:question%20closed:no)